# Application Insights API $select not returning all results when values share part of path

Tags: odata, azure-application-insights

I'm not sure if this is an OData issue or an Application Insights issue, but the App Insights API is not giving me all of the values I selected.  It works normally most of the time, but when I ask for two values that share the beginning of their path, it only gives me the second value I asked for.

Here's an example of my issue:

data:

```
{
  "count": 1,
  "type": "customEvent",
  "customDimensions": {
    "success": "true",
    "version": "ver-1"
  },
  "other": {
    "key": "val-1"
  }
},
{
  "count": 2,
  "type": "customEvent",
  "customDimensions": {
    "success": "false",
    "version": "ver-2"
  },
  "other": {
    "key": "val-2"
  }
}
```

These all return the results that I'm expecting:

Query: $select=count,type

```
{
  "count": 1,
  "type": "customEvent"
},
{
  "count": 2,
  "type": "customEvent"
}
```

Query: select=customDimensions/success,other/key

```
{
  "customDimensions": {
    "success":"true"
  },
  "other": {
    "key":"ver-1"
  }
},
{
  "customDimensions": {
    "success":"false"
  },
  "other": {
    "key":"ver-2"
  }
}
```

However, if I try to get two values that start with the same path, it only shows me the second one.

Query: select=customDimensions/success,customDimensions/version

```
{
  "customDimensions": {
    "version":"ver-1"
  }
},
{
  "customDimensions": {
    "version":"ver-2"
  }
}
```

Is this an issue with either OData or Application Insights, or is there some other way I can format my query to give me the information I want?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
You can use the query api as following to fetch the data:

```
https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/Your_application_id/query?query=requests
| where timestamp >ago(5h)
|  project customDimensions.UsersNamed, customDimensions.TenantsCoded
```

I test it in postman, see screenshot below:
[image]

Seems that your App Insights query is ok, I tested it using [this](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/events?appId=DEMO_APP&apiKey=DEMO_KEY&eventType=requests) .

I fetch the operation/name and operation/id(which starts with same path), original like this:
[image]

Then input some necessary condition, as screenshot below:
[image]

After click "Fetch" button, you can see the operation/name and operation/id are both returned.

Comment: So it looks like this is working for the sample app, but it is still not working for my application.  I keep just receiving the second value.

Comment: @RWood, it's a little wierd. It only occurs when the shared path is customDimensions, for others(shared path is operation ect) are ok as per my test. But if you only wanna get the customDimensions/success and customDimensions/version, you can use query api, please see my updated answer.