# How to select multiple CustomDimensions from Azure Application Insights API?

Tags: api, azure, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to select events that have three CustomDimensions fields set: MessageType, MessageName and MessageID.

The events also contain the content of the message, which can be quite large, so I don't want to get that in the response.

So I'm using the $select operator to select a subset of fields available in the events.

The $select query is as follows: `id, timestamp, customDimensions/MessageID, customDimensions/MessageName, customDimensions/MessageType`

No matter what I do I always get the **last** CustomDimension and not all three.
Example response:

```
 "id": "bc33c887-e100-11e8-9830-effc6d3968d7",
  "timestamp": "2018-11-05T13:42:58.240Z",
  "customDimensions": {
    "MessageType": "RESPONSE"
  }
```

Is there a special syntax for selecting more CustomDimension fields from the events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52300303/application-insights-api-select-not-returning-all-results-when-values-share-par/52307712#52307712), and I have already mailed to MS for this issue, but no feedback now.

As a workaround, you can use this solution(You can ajust the `ago(5h)` as per your need),official document [here](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Using-the-API/Query):

```
https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/Your_application_id/query?query=events
| where timestamp >ago(5h)
|  project id, timestamp, customDimensions.MessageID, customDimensions.MessageName,customDimensions.MessageType
```

Then you can test it in postman like this:
[image]

> How to get the application id and api key:

Nav to azure portal -> your application insights -> API Access blade, then you can see the `Application id`.

Then click the `Create API key` button, in the create api key page, select the `Read telemetry` checkbox, then click Generate key button. **Please remember the api key, if it's lost, you need to generate a new one**.

[image]

[image]